# How can we know the value of Symmetrickey in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I am writing one SQL command

```
    SELECT DISTINCT key_name(Encryptedcolumn) FROM tableename;
```

From above we will get the Name of the symmetric key Name. But I need to know the value of that symmetric key. 
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by the value of the symmetric key? Do you mean the name of the certificate that was used, the encryption algorithm? Something else?

Comment: No, I was create the certificate and symmetric key and did the the encryption and decryption. perfectly. Here I knew the name of symmetric key, but i dont know the value like - DS7FS5FWW7SFS57DE

Comment: The details of symmetric keys are stored in `sys.symmetric_keys`. The actual key values are encrypted and cannot easily be retrieved. You can [open the key and export it, though](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-identical-symmetric-keys-on-two-servers) (again, with encryption).

Comment: yes did everything.                                                                                           use database
go
select * from sys.symmetric_keys. From this i can find name, id, length, algorithm_desc, create_date, modifiy_date, key_guid, providetypr etx... but i did not know the value for that symmetric key  like- GSDS4SD46S5XXXXXX9A94D4

Comment: The "value" of the key is a bunch of bytes you can't access. If by "value" you mean whatever password or certificate you used to create the key, obviously that can't be retrieved, as that would mean the key is compromised. You may need to add more details on what exactly it is you think you'll achieve with the "value" of the key -- it likely is either possible, if not in the way you think, or it is not possible, due to basic security requirements. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Here what i did is 
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY  
PASSWORD = '1235@#!PshAbdc'  
CREATE CERTIFICATE SelfSignedCertificate  
WITH SUBJECT = 'Password Encryption';  
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SQLSymmetricKey  
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128  
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SelfSignedCertificate;  
ALTER TABLE UserDetails  
ADD EncryptedPassword Nvarchar(MAX )NULL  
SELECT FirstName, LastName,LoginID,UserPassword,EncryptedPassword,  
CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), DecryptByKey(EncryptedPassword)) AS 'DecryptedPassword'  
FROM UserDetails;
 from the above what is the value of SYMMETRIC KEY . thanks

Comment: from above I got exact result of my text. text is converted to encrypted text and decrypted back to my text with the help of my symmetric key. I knew here my symmetric key name, but I don't know its value?

Comment: It doesn't have a value you can access, it only has a name (`SqlSymmetricKey`). The value is managed internally by SQL Server and is never required for any operation. `EncryptByKey` needs a GUID (not a name), which can be obtained with the `KEY_GUID` function -- that may be what you're looking for. Note that the code you posted does not contain any place where the key is actually used to *encrypt* the value.

Comment: thanks for your response.  when i get the encrypted value of my text. to decrypt it in online tools, I can't do it because I don't  know the symmetric key or encryption key?

Comment: Note that comments are a terrible way of posting code (they allow limited formatting and they're subject to deletion); you can always [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: Correct, you cannot decrypt values encrypted by symmetric keys in SQL Server outside of the database. The intended use case is for data that remains inside the database. If you want the ability to decrypt the data client-side, the encryption must also happen client-side. [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) is a more complicated feature where the server does not maintain the keys at all, which (when properly configured) is transparent to the client.

Comment: Last but certainly not least, note that the secure way of dealing with passwords is to *hash* them (with salt), not *encrypt* them. Most systems do not need to know the actual password, only whether the user knows the password, and that's better handled with a hash.